# Python: exclude certain text from print out of a file

Tags: python, printing

I have a file called "list" that I need to print certain information out of but not the whole file. My file is as follows:

```
pool
pool/return
pool/home
pool/home/audits
pool/home/audits/2013
pool/home/audits/2014
pool/home/exchanges
pool/home/term
pool/transfers
```

I need to print everything under "/home/" except the "audits/" section. Here is the code I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
searchfile = open('list', 'r')
for line in iter(searchfile):
    if '/home' and not 'home/audits' in line:
            print line.strip()
searchfile.close()
```

I get the following:

```
pool
pool/return
pool/home
pool/home/exchanges
pool/home/term
pool/transfers
```

But I need it to print only:

```
pool/home/exchanges
pool/home/term
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for both '/home' to be in line and 'home/audits' to be in line:

```
if '/home' in line and not 'home/audits' in line:
```

The condition `if '/home' and not 'home/audits' in line:`

get's converted to `if True and not 'home/audits' in line:`

since `bool('/home')` (or `bool('any string')`) is always True as long as the string is populated

Comment: Ashoka that worked. I just needed to adjust '/home' to 'home/'. Thank you for the response. After reading your response it made sense as to where I was wrong